# What is the difference between 失恋する and 振る?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

Both 失恋する and 振る mean to be rejected. But then are they exactly the same thing? What are the nuances between those two words?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 振る means to reject.  振られる means to *be* rejected.

Comment: When you are フラれた, then you're 失恋した. But when you're 失恋した, you're not necessarily フラれた; you can also say you're 失恋した when the person you're secretly in love with has started to go out with someone else.

Answer (score 3):

### 振{ふ}る

As istrasci noted in the comments, 振る (in relation to romance) means *"to reject"*.  In physical terms, it literally means "*to shake"* or *"to wave"*, and the romantic meanings could thus be understood as similar to the English phrasing *"to shake or wave someone off"* → *"to get rid of someone, to reject someone"*.

### 失恋{しつれん}する

Looking at this second term, the individual kanji mean *"to lose"* + *"love (especially passionate or carnal love)"*.  <s>Idiomatically, it's more like *"to lose **in** love"*, as in, *"to love someone but not get anywhere with them"* → with connotations of either *unrequited love*, or *rejected love*.</s>

I've struck out text above due to a misapprehension on my part, due in part to misleading reference materials.  After chatting some with native speakers [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28199910#28199910) and earlier, and also offline, it turns out the meaning of 失恋する is much closer to the literal spelling: forget about *"unrequited love"*, a better English gloss would be ***"to become broken-hearted"***.

### Comparison

振る then is what the rejecter does, while 失恋する is what the person in love with the rejecter does.

An example (albeit somewhat forced):

> あの子は彼を**振った**ので、彼は**失恋した**。
>   Because that girl **turned** him **down**, he **became broken-hearted**.

Note the *"became"*: the Japanese term refers to the **change of state** from in love to broken-hearted.  I've changed the usage example above accordingly.  Using a -ている form with 失恋する implies that a person is getting their heart broken multiple times, and *not* that they are in an ongoing state of broken-heartedness.

Comment: 「あの子は彼を振ったのに、彼は失恋し続けている。」 は変です。「彼はあの子にフラれたのに、(まだ)片思いし続けている。/ (まだ)あの子のことを想い続けている。」とか「あの子は彼をフッたのに、彼はまだ～」とか「彼はあの子に失恋したのに、～～」とかならいいと思いますが。

Comment: True. It's done. Once getting the elbow, how can you keep '失恋しーlosing love'?If you take  '失' off from '失恋' ,and say "あの子は彼を振ったのに、彼は（彼女を）恋し続けている," it sounds O.K.'

Comment: @choco, Yoichi, ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 1):

失恋する is opposite to 振る. 失恋する literally means “lose love,” i.e. being rejected by someone whom he or she loves. While 振る means “to reject” a romantic proposal from someone who loves him or her. Its passive form is (彼女に) 振られる. “失恋する” and “振られる” are almost similar in meaning, with the latter having a stronger nuance of getting an outright elbow.